# create reusable controls/packages in an one dtsx package in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We use SSIS for our data automation. The caveat is we don't use the normal way mentioned online. For our environment, we save the `Package.dtsx` file on a server that has a windows job that will execute it using `dtexec.exe`.

I have multiple SSIS packages to pull data from various sources (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server) and the general flow for them is the same. The table names are different but I will use `data` as the table names for one of the sources/SSIS packages.

1. backup the table `data` into `bak_data` on the destination DB
2. import new data from the source into `data`
3. compare data quality (row count) against `data` and `bak_data`
4. if data quality **does meet** our threshold, send a success e-mail (execute task against our destination DB using `db_send_dbmail`)
5. if the data quality **does not meet** our threshold, backup `data` to `bad_data` then restore from `bak_data` to `data` and send failure e-mail

Since the steps are always the same I thought I could use Control Flow Package Parts and then just use variables for the table names and what not.

But upon further investigation I realized I cannot do that because the Control Flow Package `.dtsxp` is a separate file referenced in/from the `Package.dtsx` file?

I can copy it to our automation server but not sure if that will be enough to work when `Package.dtsx` is executed using `dtexec`.

Is there anyway I can create reusable controls/packages with my constraint/situation?

Comment: Yeah, package parts seems like it'd be ideal until you get into it and it doesn't do a darn thing that's useful.

Comment: What I'm not getting yet from reading your question is do you have something that already does this or you're trying to built it from scratch? If it exists, can you elaborate on the existing SSIS mechanics?

Comment: @billinkc Well I have multiple packages (spread across different solutions) that do all this manually. Each package basically does the above steps for different tables in different sources. All of them write to different tables in the same destination DB.

Comment: Still not clear on the requirements but my goto these days is to Biml everything. It won't get over the data flow task's requirement of stable/consistent metadata but it's at least a means of generating it consistently and easily

Comment: I have not used BIML for SSIS and am not sure how. I don't see a way to create a new BIML file in my Visual Studio in the SSIS solution. I will look into it.

Comment: I will be deleting this question as I learned that any references to a Control Flow Package Parts are saved inside the Package.dtsx so I can still execute it using dtexec.